# React giving a blank white page on rendering the Chat component, after integrating firebase for messages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a chat app. The app returns a blank page after the login page, instead of showing the chat section. The problem is with the firebase code which I used for getting the messages from the firebase database. If I don't render the Chat section, then the Sidebar section turns out to render well. The Chat component code is:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./Chat.css";
import { Avatar, IconButton } from "@material-ui/core";
import { SearchOutlined } from "@material-ui/icons";
import { AttachFile } from "@material-ui/icons";
import MoreVertIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MoreVert";
import MicIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Mic";
import InsetEmoticonIcon from "@material-ui/icons/InsertEmoticon";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import db from "./firebase";

function Chat() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [photo, setphoto] = useState("");
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState();
  const { roomId } = useParams();
  const [roomName, setRoomName] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (roomId) {
      console.log("Change");
      db.collection("rooms")
        .doc(roomId)
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => setRoomName(snapshot.data().name));
      db.collection("rooms")
        .doc(roomId)
        .collection("messages")
        .orderBy("timestamp", "asc")
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
          setMessages(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()))
        );
    }
  }, [roomId]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setphoto(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000));
  }, []);
  const sendMessage = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("You typed a message");
    setInput("");
  };
  return (
    <div className="chat">
      <div className="chat-header">
        <Avatar
          src={`https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/pixel-art/${photo}.svg`}
        />
        <div className="chat-headerInfo">
          <h2>{roomName}</h2>
          <p>Last Seen</p>
        </div>
        <div className="chat-headerRight">
          <IconButton>
            <SearchOutlined />
          </IconButton>
          <IconButton>
            <AttachFile />
          </IconButton>
          <IconButton>
            <MoreVertIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="chat-body">
        {messages.map((message) => (
          <p className="chat-message chatReceiver">
            <span className="sender">{message.name}</span>
            {message.message}
            <span className="timestamp">
              {new Date(message.timestamp?.toDate()).toUTCString}
            </span>
          </p>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="chat-footer">
        <InsetEmoticonIcon />
        <form>
          <input
            value={input}
            onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Type a message"
          />
          <button onClick={sendMessage} type="submit">
            Send a message
          </button>
        </form>
        <MicIcon />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Chat;
```

Github link of the project : https://github.com/aditramdas/Chat-App/tree/main/chat-app-new/src

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: The warning is:WARNING in [eslint]
src\App.js
  Line 1:17:   'useState' is defined but never used           no-unused-vars
  Line 10:20:  'dispatch' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

Comment: I mean in the browsers console. Not in the terminal.

Comment: The starting of the error goes like this:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at Chat (Chat.js:51:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16293:1)

Comment: `const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);`

Comment: Thank you so much!!!You are a life saver. I was on this for quite some time now.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski , could you please post it as answer so it could also help the community.